# Find $\nabla F (2,0,-3)$ given the data

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, function-and-relation-composition

Two functions are composed so
$ F(u,v,w)=f(x(u,v,w),y(u,v,w))$
and it is known that
$$x(-2,0,3)=-1  \,\,\,\,\,\,, \,\,\,\,\,\,y(-2,0,3)=1$$
$$\nabla x(-2,0,3)=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4})  \,\,\,\,\,\,, \,\,\,\,\,\,\nabla y(-2,0,3)=(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{7}) $$
$$\nabla f(-1,1)=(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3} ) $$
Aslo it is known that $x$ and $y$ are differentiable on $(-2,0,3)$ and that $f$ is differentiable on $(-1,1)$
Given this I can find that $F(-2,0,3)=(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3} )$ but can I find $\nabla F (-2,0,3)$ given the data that I have? and if so how?

Comment: Do you know the Chain Rule for partial derivatives? For example, what is a formula for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}$ here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing:
$$\vec{x} = \langle x,y \rangle \qquad \vec{u} = \langle u,v,w \rangle $$
we find the derivative matrix using the chain rule:
\begin{align*}
F(\vec{u}) &= f(\vec{x}(\vec{u})) \\
\mathbf{D}F(\vec{u}) &= \mathbf{D}f(\vec{x}(\vec{u})) \cdot \mathbf{D}\vec{x}(\vec{u}) \\
\mathbf{D}F(\vec{u})|_{\vec{u}=(-2,0,3)} &= \mathbf{D}f(\vec{x}(\vec{u}))|_{\vec{u}=(-2,0,3)} \cdot \mathbf{D}\vec{x}(\vec{u})|_{\vec{u}=(-2,0,3)} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{7} \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{5} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{7} \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

More often, rather than using the derivative matrices and chain rule in the above form, it is commonly seen to write out the equations:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial u}f(x(u,v,w),y(u,v,w)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial v} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial v}f(x(u,v,w),y(u,v,w))  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial w} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial w}f(x(u,v,w),y(u,v,w))  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial w} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}
\end{align*}

which arise from seeing the relations between the variables:
[image]

Both ways give the same answer and are the same concept - the matrix form of the chain rule is simply a way to generalize and shorthand. The derivative (the gradient) evaluated at the point is then:

$$ \mathbf{D} F(-2,0,3) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{5} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{7} \end{bmatrix} $$